# Type-safe decorator for private method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator

I tried to implement a decorator in typescript that can only be applied to async functions.
If the decorator is applied to a none async function the compile should raise an error.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
type AsyncFunction = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

function MyDecorator(/* params as needed */) {
    return function <P extends string>(target: Record<P, AsyncFunction> , propertyKey: P) {
        console.log("Implementation of MyDecorator")
    }
}

class SomeClassWithPrivateMethod {

    @MyDecorator()
    private async somePrivateMethod() {

    }

    @MyDecorator()
    async somePublicMethod() {

    }

}
```

The problem is, that it does not work for private methods with the following error message:

> Argument of type 'SomeClassWithPrivateMethod' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"somePrivateMethod", AsyncFunction>'.   
> Property 'somePrivateMethod' is private in type 'SomeClassWithPrivateMethod' but not in type 'Record<"somePrivateMethod", AsyncFunction>'.

What do I have to change to make it work for private methods?

Comment: pls share minimum reproducable example with private method

Comment: @captain-yossarian I have updated my question. Create a new file and copy-paste the code example from above. The decorator feature must be anabled in the tsconfig file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my use case I found a very simple solution 
- tested with typescript 4.6.3 -

Instead of applying a contraint to the target parameter, it is possible restrict the descriptor parameter to a specific type:

```js
type AsyncFunction = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

function MyDecorator(/* params as needed */) {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<AsyncFunction>) {
        console.log("Implementation of MyDecorator")
    }
}
```

`TypedPropertyDescriptor<AsyncFunction>` is the key here. `TypedPropertyDescriptor` is a built in type from typescript.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript does not support `'private'|'public'|'static'` modifiers inside type declaration.

You can declare `static` modifier as index type in `class`. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#static-index-signatures)

`Private` type is treated in different way then other types. You can treat it as a some kind of nominal type.

Consider this example:

```js
type AsyncFunction = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

abstract class Base {
    private async somePrivateMethod() { }
}

function MyDecorator() {
    return function <P extends string>(target: Base, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("Implementation of MyDecorator")
    }
}

class SomeClassWithPrivateMethod {   
    @MyDecorator()
    private async somePrivateMethod() {}

    @MyDecorator()
    async somePublicMethod() { }

}
```

Despite the fact that TS has structural type system, you are getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'SomeClassWithPrivateMethod' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Base'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property 'somePrivateMethod'.(2345)
```

Hence, private method of `Base` is not equal to `private` method of `SomeClassWithPrivateMethod`

If you remove `private` flag from both of them - it will compile.

Since it is impossible to create a type/class/interface which will represent private type of `SomeClassWithPrivateMethod` you can't apply this decorator to private method in more or less safe and what more important **generic** way.

However there is a workaround.

You can use `SomeClassWithPrivateMethod` class type for `target` argument. It will work

```js
type AsyncFunction = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>

abstract class Base {
    async somePrivateMethod() { }
}

function MyDecorator() {
    return function <P extends string>(target: SomeClassWithPrivateMethod, prop: P, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("Implementation of MyDecorator")
    }
}

class SomeClassWithPrivateMethod {
    @MyDecorator()
    private async somePrivateMethod() { }

    @MyDecorator()
    async somePublicMethod() { }

}
```

OR use `target:unknown`.

```js
function MyDecorator() {
    return function <P extends string>(target: unknown, prop: P, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("Implementation of MyDecorator")
    }
}
```

Comment: I really need to ensure, that my Decorator is only applied to async functions. Otherwise an error would be thrown at runtime, which leads to bad bugs. This is what my question is all about. I don't see how your workaround ensures this requirement. Can you point out how this works in your example? Thanks.

Comment: What about my second example?

Comment: I have tried both of your solutions and all of them allow to apply MyDecorator to a non-asnyc function without any Compiler error or warning.